# Discord.py Intents.members won't be set to True in class:

Tags: discord.py

I try to use `guild.fetch_members(limit=None)` in my class:
In an earlier version it worked but won't anymore...

Like in the introduction in the [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#basic-concepts) described I created a class for my bot now I am facing the problem that Intents.members aren't enabled.

```
Intents = discord.Intents.default()
Intents.members = True
Intents.presences = False

class OverlordBot(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(platform.system())
        print(Intents.members)

        # loop for every guild
        for guild in self.guilds:
            self.__amountGuilds += 1

            # loop for every channel in every guild
            for channels in guild.channels:
                self.__amountChannels += 1

            # loop for every user in every server
            members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=None).flatten()
            for member in members:
                self.__memberList.append(member.id)
```

And here is the error-stack:

```
Linux
True
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anon/Documents/git/overlordbot/Overlord_vrs_4/main/Main.py", line 133, in on_ready
    members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=None).flatten()
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1313, in fetch_members
    raise ClientException('Intents.members must be enabled to use this.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Intents.members must be enabled to use this.
```

Funnily this error only occurs on Linux-Systems. It works perfectly fine on my Windows-machine and since I want to run this bot on my RaspberryPi I must resolve this problem.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Have you enabled them in the developer portal? Also - are you passing the intents to the bot? Can you add the part where you're instantiating the bot?

Comment: yes it works on my Windows-computer but not on my ArchLinux or RaspberryPi

Comment: What is the error on those systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone who tried to help me here.
I finally found what the problem was.

at the end of file when instantiating the client I needed to give the intents as a parameter.

```
client = OverlordBot(intents=intents)
client.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove the class and use the code as docs say. If you don't want, try to copy-paste the intents line into the class() too.